# D3 Beginner - having some issues with scale

Tags: d3.js

I recently started working on D3 and found what feels like a good introductory tutorial by Mr Scott Murray at alignedleft.com.  I'm currently trying to replicate his information on [scale](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales), but I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to solve.  I've gone so far as to copy and paste his code and it isn't working.

I'm probably using a newer version of D3 than the tutorial is written on and I'm just missing something that changed in a version?

I'm currently using d3 version 4.3.0

The code I'm working with is

```
var dataset = [
          [5, 20], [480, 90], [250, 50], [100, 33], [330, 95],
          [410, 12], [475, 44], [25, 67], [85, 21], [220, 88]
        ];

var w = 500;
var h = 200;

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
               .range([0, h]);
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
               .range([0, w]);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", h).attr("width", w);

svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).enter().append("circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
  return xScale(d[0]);
}).attr("cy", function(d){
  return yScale(d[1]);
}).attr("r", 5);
```

Any guidance or reason for this not working would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3.js version four will break a fair amount of code from version three. The reason being the "great namespace flattening" of version 4.

The following methods relating to scales have changed:

> ```
> d3.scale.linear ↦ d3.scaleLinear
> d3.scale.sqrt ↦ d3.scaleSqrt
> d3.scale.pow ↦ d3.scalePow
> d3.scale.log ↦ d3.scaleLog
> d3.scale.quantize ↦ d3.scaleQuantize
> d3.scale.threshold ↦ d3.scaleThreshold
> d3.scale.quantile ↦ d3.scaleQuantile
> d3.scale.identity ↦ d3.scaleIdentity
> d3.scale.ordinal ↦ d3.scaleOrdinal
> d3.time.scale ↦ d3.scaleTime
> d3.time.scale.utc ↦ d3.scaleUtc
> ```

So, your `d3.scale.linear()` should read `d3.scaleLinear()`

Comment: Andrew - Thank you so much for your quick and prompt response.  I've been racking my brain and trying various searches to find an answer and had not found it.  I guess the question I should now ask is should I go back to version 3 for learning or is version 4 now the standard?

Comment: That's a trickier and subjective question, v4.0.0 was only released in June 2016, so a lot of examples, tutorials, and questions still use version 3. So for learning, that might be easier, though with time the volume of version 4 resources will pass that of version 3. Using version four in your own code should not be a significant barrier to understanding and learning d3 based on version 3 examples. The changes are documented quite well at: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md.

Comment: Andrew Reid - Thank you for that I will look into it